# Trying to understand Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function 'query' that 'awaits' for the pool.query to return the results.

```
// db.js

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: isProduction,
});

export const query = async ({ text, values }) => {
  const start = Date.now();

  try {
    const results = await pool.query(text, values);
    const duration = Date.now() - start;
    logger.info(`executed query: ${text} duration: ${duration} rows: ${results.rowCount}`);
    return results.rows;
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`error: ${e}`);
  }
};
```

In another async function getUser() I'm 'awaiting' the query function to finish before returning the data.

---

```
// users.js

export const getUser = async (email) => {
  const text = `
      SELECT (user_id, email) FROM users 
      WHERE email = $1
  `;
  const values = [email];

  try {
    const data = await query({ text, values });
    // ^ vscode says above await is doing nothing
    return data.rows[0];
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`error: ${e}`);
  }
};
```

---

Then in yet another async function I'm awaiting the getUser function

---

```
// auth.js

export const SignIn = async (email, password) => {
  const userRecord = await getUser(email);
  if (!userRecord) {
    throw new Error('User not registered');
  }

  logger.silly('Checking password');
  const validPassword = await argon2.verify(userRecord.password, password);
  if (validPassword) {
    logger.silly('Password is valid!');
    logger.silly('Generating JWT');
    const token = await generateToken(userRecord);

    const user = { id: userRecord.id, email: userRecord.email };
    return { user, token };
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid Password');
  }
};
```

---

Inside vsCode I'm getting a warning "await has no effect on the type of this expression." only when 'awaiting' the query function call, but not when 'awaiting' the getUser function call. What am I missing here?

Comment: Any function defined with `async` returns a Promise, and awaiting a promise has an effect. Perhaps you are importing a different method called query. Based on the code shown, the warning is spurious.

Comment: I only have the one query function.

Comment: Do you have `import {query} from './db'` at the top?

Comment: yes, I have import { query } from '../loaders/db.js'

Comment: And your `db.js` above is the file at `../loaders/db.js`? Your query returns a Promise.

Comment: I just figured it out, for some reason the jsDoc comment above my query function is causing the issue. - thanks for your help though

Comment: That would do it. VS Code will honor the JSDoc comments in a `.js` file. For async functions, return type inference, I.E. leaving off the `{type}` in `@returns {type}` is probably better. Otherwise you have to write `@returns {Promise<something>}`

Answer (score 0):

What does `query` return? If `results.rows` is a promise then that might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: The query function returns the results from node-postgres querying the database. I was following this project structure, https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure, but tried converting it into async/await.